# PHP Multiple Pictures Uploader

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I'm looking for a multiple image uploader. I prefer to not use MySQL database and no flash.

Also if it is possible to use some javascript (jQuery maybe?) to perform some cropping and scaling.

The best in all worlds would be to have a nice jQuery plugin which perform all that.

Can you please give me your suggestions?

B.R Carl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at http://www.plupload.com/ which provides fallback engines if certain plugins are not available.

Depending on the engine used, it also provides functionality for resizing images on the client side.

And Yes, it's using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but I know a lot of people who have been using [noSWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/noswfupload/), although I'm not sure if this is being maintained anymore.

As far as jQuery for cropping is concerned, you can follow a method [like here...](http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-crop-an-image-using-jquery-and-php)